# Is there a difference between page caches and disk caches?

Tags: caching, storage, page-caching

I apologize if this has already been answered, I just came across some textbook references that seem to be using the terms "page cache" and "disk cache" as separate entities, but I always was under the impression that they were the same thing.

Comment: Any quotes or references would help in answering the question...

Answer (score 1):

A page cache is used to speed up access to images and data on disk. It is used to cache the logical contents of a file a page at a time and is accessed via the file and offset within the file. As pages are read into memory from disk, they are cached in the page cache.

Answer (score 0):

The link below answers your question
https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-memory-cache-and-disk-cache-in-Chrome